# StructureMap and factory classes

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have som factory classes in my code and do not like the call to Structermap. How should i do this the right way?

```
class ManagerBaseFactory
{
    public ManagerBase GetInstance(SomeEnum e)
    {
        Type t;

        switch (e)
        {
            case SomeEnum.A:
                t = typeof(Manager1);
            case SomeEnum.B:
                t = typeof(Manager2);
            case SomeEnum.C:
                t = typeof(Manager3);
        }
        return (ManagerBase)StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance(t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the problem in using structure map this way. What do you not like about the current solution?

You could use named instances that you will not even need the factory anymore. [structuremap link](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/InstanceExpression.htm#section14)

```
public class ServicesRegistry : Registry
{
    public ServicesRegistry()
    {
        For< ManagerBase >().Use< Manager1 >().Named("A");
        For< ManagerBase >().Use< Manager2 >().Named("B");
        For< ManagerBase >().Use< Manager3 >().Named("C");
    }
}
```

You can than retrieve the correct one by just calling

```
SomeEnum e = SomeEnum.A;
ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<ManagerBase>(e.ToString());
```

Comment: ManagerBaseFactory is not testable. I'll like to have onlye one call to Structermap in the Main.

Comment: I am not sure i undestand this configuration. How does Processor look like?

Comment: This is just an example I took from the structure manual and the processor is not important. This thing is you can use structure map to get an specific instance of a object (in you car ManagerBase) by a name that in your case can be the enumerator value. I updated the example to let it match you specific needs I think.

Comment: Thanks I get it now. Stil I have a problem with calling Structermap in all my factories.

Comment: If you are talking about the fact that ManagerBaseFactory is not testable that depend on what you want to test. But you can configure structuremap to return mock objects of you normal instances that is one of the reasons to use library like structuremap.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely do not want your ManagerBaseFactory to use the container, you could give it access to all of the ManagerBase implementations from the container, and have it return the correct one. When StructureMap sees an IEnumerable of a type in a constructor, it will inject all instances of that type that it knows about.

```
class ManagerBaseFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ManagerBase> _managers;

    public ManagerBaseFactory(IEnumerable<ManagerBase> managers)
    {
        _managers = managers;
    }

    public ManagerBase GetInstance(SomeEnum e)
    {
        Type t;

        switch (e)
        {
            case SomeEnum.A:
                t = typeof(Manager1);
                break;
            case SomeEnum.B:
                t = typeof(Manager2);
                break;
            case SomeEnum.C:
                t = typeof(Manager3);
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }
        return _managers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.GetType().Equals(t));
    }
}
```

And of course you need to make sure all of your ManagerBase implementations are loaded in the container:

```
var container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.Scan(scan =>
    {
        scan.TheCallingAssembly();
        scan.AddAllTypesOf<ManagerBase>();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what part you object to. One improvement you could make is to have `ManagerBaseFactory` take in an `IContainer` in its constructor, which you can use in place of the `ObjectFactory` static gateway. Then you can pull `ManagerBaseFactory` out of the container, and the container will inject itself into the factory. The factory will be easier to unit test without the static dependency.

You could also put the return statements directly in the switch so you can take advantage of generics:

```
case SomeEnum.A:
  return _container.GetInstance<Manager1>();
```

Comment: ManagerBaseFactory is not testable, since it uses the DI container.

Comment: It absolutely is testable. That is why I suggested taking in IContainer instead of using ObjectFactory. In your test, create a new instance of Container, load it with the minimum you need for the scenario you are testing, and pass it to ManagerBaseFactory. Or just stub out IContainer.